# Algorithm for finding all sets that fulfill a condition?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, gap

Lets say I have a set of none-negative integers of given length $n$ where $n>0$.
$$m=\left(m_1,...,m_n\right)$$
A number can appear more than once in the same set. The same set or numbers can also be arranged in a different order. What is the most efficient way of finding all such sets which fulfill the condition:
$$\sum^{n}_{k=1}k \cdot m_k=n$$
I am looking for a algorithm I can use for a computer program.

Comment: What is $k(m_k)$?

Comment: @ajotatxe I think it means $km_k$

Comment: Are you trying to find all solutions $(m_1,\dots,m_n)$ in non-negative integers  to the equation $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^nkm_k=n}$?  Is that really supposed to be $n$ on both sides of the equation?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes to is supposed to be the same variable on both sides.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What approaches have you considered?  What success have you had?

Comment: Do you want to just count how many there are, or really generate all such n-tuples? If the former, then dynamic programming techniques can give you the answer pretty quick.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Generate all of them

Comment: @saulspatz Not that much really. Though I do know some conditions for each integer in the set. For example every element in the set has to be less than or equal to $n$ since otherwise the sum would automatically be larger than $n$. Also $(n,0,...,0)$ and $(0,...,0,n)$ will always be a solution. Also according to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284720/confused-by-fa%c3%a0-di-brunos-formula-notation $m_k\leq\frac{n}{k}$ is true. Also if n is even $m_{\frac{n}{2}}=2$ and the rest being $0$ is a solution. Otherwise not much.

Comment: If you have to generate all the solutions, I can't see any alternative to backtrack.  You should make sure to backtrack when you know that no future assignment can work.  That is, when you get to level $k,$ if you've already accounted for more than $n-k$, instead of assigning $m_k=0$ and going on to level $k+1$, you should backtrack to level $k-1$ immediately.

Comment: are the numbers 0 padded, otherwise how is n of length n

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yes the set consists of none negative integers which includes zero.

Comment: @saulspatz I was wondering if I should also post this question on stack overflow maybe people there have some ideas.

Comment: I mean is 00000008 valid ? How about 8.0000000 ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee If you mean sets such as $(8,0,0,...,0)$ and $(0,...0,0,8)$ then yes.

Comment: I thought The sum had to equal n, but that must be mistake as $n$ has less than n digits in base 10 by $n=2$

Comment: @Jonas Sure, why not?  I think you ought to put in a link to this question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact you are looking for [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). Each time a solution to the question is found 
it in fact determines a partition, only it is represented in a different way. Your algorithm should start with generating the partitions of $n$ and then collecting similar results. Example (in GAP) with $n=10$:

```
gap> p10 := Partitions(10);
[ [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],    
  [ 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
  [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 3, 3, 2, 1, 1 ], [ 3, 3, 2, 2 ], [ 3, 3, 3, 1 ], [ 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 4, 2, 2, 1, 1 ], [ 4, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 4, 3, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 3 ], [ 4, 4, 1, 1 ], [ 4, 4, 2 ], [ 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 5, 2, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 5, 2, 2, 1 ], [ 5, 3, 1, 1 ], [ 5, 3, 2 ], [ 5, 4, 1 ],
  [ 5, 5 ], [ 6, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 6, 2, 1, 1 ], [ 6, 2, 2 ], [ 6, 3, 1 ],
  [ 6, 4 ], [ 7, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 7, 2, 1 ], [ 7, 3 ], [ 8, 1, 1 ], [ 8, 2 ],
  [ 9, 1 ], [ 10 ] ]
gap> List(p10, Collected);
[ [ [ 1, 10 ] ], [ [ 1, 8 ], [ 2, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 6 ], [ 2, 2 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ] ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ] ], [ [ 2, 5 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 7 ], [ 3, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 5 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 3, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 3, 2 ] ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ],
  [ [ 2, 2 ], [ 3, 2 ] ], [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 3, 3 ] ], [ [ 1, 6 ], [ 4, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 4, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 4, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ] ], [ [ 3, 2 ], [ 4, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 4, 2 ] ], [ [ 2, 1 ], [ 4, 2 ] ], [ [ 1, 5 ], [ 5, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 5, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ] ], [ [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ] ], [ [ 5, 2 ] ], [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 6, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ] ], [ [ 2, 2 ], [ 6, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ] ], [ [ 4, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 7, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 3, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 8, 1 ] ], [ [ 2, 1 ], [ 8, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 9, 1 ] ], [ [ 10, 1 ] ] ]
```

from which the solutions $\{10,0,\ldots\}$, $\{8,1,0,\ldots\}$, $\{6,2,\ldots\}$,
$\{4,3,\ldots\}$, $\{2,4,\ldots\}$,$\{0,5,\ldots\}$,$\{7,0,1,\ldots\}$, $\{5,1,1\ldots\}$, etc.

Comment: See also the [GAP manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap16.html) for `NrPartitions` and `IteratorOfPartitions` and more - useful when you want to check how many partitions are there, iterate over them without creating a huge list which may not fit into memory, and also filter some special kinds of partitions.

Comment: First of all thank you soo much! Would I not also have to try out every arrangement for each partition? What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: @Jonas what exactly do you mean by arrangement? example?

Comment: @MarcBogaerts Sorry overlooked something in your answer which answered my question. Thanks for this. This helped soo much!!!